# Como "truncar" tabela para reiniciar do menor valor de auto incremento

Tags: sql, sql-server

A `tabela_A` possui um campo `id` com auto incremento. Preciso limpar a tabela com algo semelhante ao comando `truncate` só que limpando apenas o registro a partir do `id = x`.

Por exemplo:

```
id col1
1  A
3  B
4  C
5  D
30 E
32 F
33 G
34 H
```

O resultado esperado seria algo como:

```
TRUNCATE table WHERE id >=30
```

E retornasse

```
id col1
1  A
3  B
4  C
5  D
```

Comment: Tem algo que impeça você de fazer: DELETE FROM table WHERE id >= 30?

Comment: Fazendo isso, a coluna `id` continuará auto incrementando com valores `>= 30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro nós removemos os registros usando

```
DELETE FROM tabela WHERE id >= 30
```

Depois nós resetamos o contador de autoincremento usando

```
declare @ultimoID int
SELECT @ultimoID = Coalesce(MAX(Id), 0) FROM tabela
DBCC CHECKIDENT (tabela, RESEED, @ultimoID)
```

Mas não é uma boa idéia reutilizar um número de ID para identificar um registro diferente do original

Comment: Obrigado pelo aviso, mas foi apenas alguns testes.